# Какой нужен знак препинания? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Нельзя проводить по линиям рисунка карандашом или пером это портит листы книги.*
Нужно ли ставить запятую или другой знак препинания в этом предложении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это сложное предложение, здесь знак перед "это" необходим. Согласно Розенталю, наличие слова "это" является условием, благоприятствующим постановке тире. Хотя возможна постановка и запятой и двоеточия.

> Ты не печалься, это портит цвет лица и насыщает воздух микробами. (Л. Андреев)
>
> Только не плачь: это портит цвет лица, будешь бледная, со вздутыми глазами. (Гарин-Михайловский)

Comment: 1. Почему это предложение сложное? 2. Ссылочку на Розенталя не дадите? (Не каждый спрашивающий, впервые появляющийся на форуме, вообще-то знает — кто это.)  3. Точки перед скобками надо перенести в самый конец предложения.

Comment: В итоге-то, что нужно ставить?

Answer (score 1):

**Вместо вступления**

Решая задачи по пунктуации, мы обычно выбираем один их трех основных знаков – **запятую, тире или двоеточие**. Чтобы правильно выбрать, изучаем очень-очень  много правил, а потом делаем вывод: здесь можно поставить **запятую, тире или двоеточие.** А тогда зачем учили правила? **Где логика?**

Решение

***Нельзя проводить по линиям рисунка карандашом или пером – это портит листы книги.***

Предложение **бессоюзное сложное**, без знака никак не обойтись. Ах, да, надо указать **грамматические основы**. Первое предложение безличное инфинитивное, сказуемое – *нельзя проводить*. Второе предложение двусоставное,  *это портит* – подлежащее и сказуемое.

Мы не можем поставить все три знака, мы должны выбрать, **иначе задачу не следует считать решенной.**

Поэтому ставим тире и объясняем свой выбор.

Прежде всего, Розенталь так велит, но только надо убедиться, что это действительно **присоединительные** отношения.

Розенталь:http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

9. Если вторая часть бессоюзного сложного предложения представляет собой присоединительное предложение, перед ней ставится тире (возможно вставить слово это, которое иногда имеется в самом предложении): Идёт большая вода — это всего интереснее (Горб.);

**Вот и в грамматике написано:** распространительно-присоединительное значение, а если точнее, то пояснительно-комментирующее. А если еще точнее, второе предложение является дополнительным **комментарием** к уже сказанному.  **Анафорическое** (отсылающее назад) местоимение ЭТО относится ко всему первому предложению.

**А как же примеры с двоеточием и запятой**, там тоже анафорическое ЭТО?

В общем случае – да, двоеточие и запятая тоже ставятся, да только окончательный выбор делается **по интонационной структуре предложения.** 
Знаки препинания – это **нотные знаки**.  Как вы их поставите, так и будет прочитано предложение и обозначены его смысловые оттенки.

Тире здесь **присоединительное**, от присоединительной запятой отличается наличием большей **паузы.** Сравнить: ***Ты не печалься, это портит цвет лица и насыщает воздух микробами.*** Здесь второе предложение содержит основную часть информации, поэтому переходим к нему практически без паузы.

А вот двоеточие всегда **пояснительное**. Сравнить:  ***Только не плачь: это портит цвет лица, будешь бледная, со вздутыми глазами.***  Вторая часть распространенная, со своими знаками препинания и собственной интонацией, поэтому делается увеличенная предупредительная пауза (она обозначается двоеточием), а далее  раскрывается содержание.

Три разные структуры и три разных знака препинания.